# How to get auto-generated row primary key via Ruby PostgreSQL gem?

Tags: ruby, postgresql

My table in PostgreSQL looks like this:

```
CREATE TABLE user (
  id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
  name VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL
)
```

I'm using Ruby [pg](https://github.com/ged/ruby-pg) gem to add a record to the table:

```
c = PG.connect(dbname: 'foo')
id = c.exec_params('INSERT INTO user (name) VALUES ($1)', ['Jeff']).oid_value
```

I'm getting `nil` back, instead of the auto-generated `id` of the new record. What is the right way to get it back?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the [docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.1/static/datatype-oid.html), if the object id you're retrieving isn't set, thus nil.

You either have to set the object id yourself, or use `returning` like this:

```
res  = conn.exec("INSERT INTO users (name) VALUES ('john') returning id")
res[0]['id']
#=> 1
```